# Is it Possible to Have own scrubber for MPMoviePlayercontroller

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play videos. I am using MPMoviePlayer, but I don't want to use the controls provided by MPMoviePlayer. So I am trying to create my own custom controls. All the functionality like play, pause, fullscreen, forward, backward are done. The only problem is with the scrubber. I am having one UISlider but I don't know how exactly work with this. How to track the currently playing video time? How to play video from where I will slide the thumb of slider?
If anyone knows this kindly help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem. I figured out how to create custom movie controls and put it up on [github](https://github.com/joshgrenon/CustomMoviePlayer). Let me know if that helps. Feel free to ask me any questions if you want details.

Answer (score 0):

First, we should note that all of this is possible in iOS 3.2+, if you are OK not to support iOS 3.1.x.

In iOS 3.2+, MPMoviePlayerController implements the MPMediaPlayback protocol, meaning that it responds to play, stop, etc., all the controls you would expect -- sounds like you already have some of this working.  Please see the [reference for the MPMediaPlayback protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback).

To get the MPMoviePlayerController to stop showing its own controls, do this on initialization:

```
yourPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

Finally, to get the scrubber to work, you need to set the UISlider valueChanged: callback to something, and update the value of `currentPlaybackTime` property.  If you want to seek 10 seconds in:

```
yourPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = 10;
```

Comment: i am using the default scrubber, but when i seek backwards the video plays but the audio stops, also if i seek forward by a huge amount then too the audio stops. Any idea's?